# iOS8 - Asking for remote push notifications

Tags: ios, permissions, ios8, push-notification

Two questions about changes in iOS8 for the user to accept push notifications (as well as notifications such as badges and so).

**1) I am using the current approach which is working fine both on iOS7 and iOS8**

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)
categories:nil];        
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];        
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

This is completely working as push and alert are working and I got the token in the didRegister delegate method, but I am never asked with a pop-up as it used to be the case. Even if I completely delete the app from my phone?
Why that? Does the OS keep in memory privacy settings for apps even if they have been deleted ?

**2) I saw some people suggesting to ask for remote notifications in the following delegate**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{        
    NSLog(@"registered for notifications settings %@",notificationSettings);        
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

**Why that ?**

Answer (score 0):

**From document**, `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings` this method callback will be made upon calling -`[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]`. The settings the user has granted to the application will be passed in as the second argument. This means, once we get user permission (or if we already got before), then this method will call, where we can register the app for remote notification by calling, `[application registerForRemoteNotifications]`.